# create unique list and count of array items in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have the following source array:

```
const list = [
    {
        students: [ 'peter', 'bob', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'thomas', 'sarah', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'john', 'sarah', 'jack']
    }
];
```

and i want to get the unique student names and their count, final result should be like:

```
{
    'john': 3,
    'sarah': 2,
    'thomas': 1,
    'jack': 1,
    'peter': 1,
    'bob': 1
}
```

here is my attempt:

```
const unique = list.reduce(function(total, curr){
  const students = curr.students;
  for (c of students) {
    if (!total[c]) {
      total[c] = 1
    } else {
      total[c] += 1;
    }
  }
  return total;

}, {});
```

is there a better way to do it? or faster and cleaner way? thanks

Comment: Your expected output has the most frequently occurring names first in the object - is that required? (it's possible to achieve, just kinda odd to be a requirement, since a good script probably shouldn't depend on property order)

Comment: yeah i'd have it ordered too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd flatten the arrays first, then count up with `reduce`:

```js
const list = [
    {
        students: [ 'peter', 'bob', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'thomas', 'sarah', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'john', 'sarah', 'jack']
    }
];


const allStudents = list.flatMap(({ students }) => students);
const count = allStudents.reduce((a, name) => {
  a[name] = (a[name] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(count);
```

If you want the properties to be ordered as well, then take the `Object.entries` of the object, sort it, then turn it back into an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const list = [
    {
        students: [ 'peter', 'bob', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'thomas', 'sarah', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'john', 'sarah', 'jack']
    }
];


const allStudents = list.flatMap(({ students }) => students);
const count = allStudents.reduce((a, name) => {
  a[name] = (a[name] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
const sorted = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(count).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
);
console.log(sorted);
```

If your environment doesn't support flatMap, or fromEntries, use a polyfill, or flatten/group with a different method:

```js
const list = [
    {
        students: [ 'peter', 'bob', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'thomas', 'sarah', 'john']
    },
    {
        students: [ 'john', 'sarah', 'jack']
    }
];


const allStudents = [].concat(...list.map(({ students }) => students));
const count = allStudents.reduce((a, name) => {
  a[name] = (a[name] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
const sortedEntries = Object.entries(count).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
const sortedObj = sortedEntries.reduce((a, [prop, val]) => {
  a[prop] = val;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(sortedObj);
```

Keep in mind that object property order is only specified in ES6+ environments. While `Object.fromEntries` isn't guaranteed by the specification to create an object in the same order as the entries, *it does anyway*, in any implementation I've ever encountered, luckily. (If you're still worried about it, you can use the old-fashioned `reduce` method to create the object instead, like in the third snippet)

Comment: TypeError: list.flatMap is not a function

Comment: Change it to `[].concat(...list.map(({ students }) => students))` or `list.map(({ students }) => students).flat()`.

Comment: @storis if `list.flatMap is not a function`, what browser or version of nodejs are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Try using functional programming: combination of map and 2 reduce methods.

```
const listMapped = list.map(it=> it.students)

const listReduced = listMapped.reduce((acc, rec) => {
return [...acc.concat(rec)]
}, [])

const listCounted = listReduced.reduce((acc, rec) => {
acc[rec]
? acc[rec] += 1
: acc[rec] = 1
return acc 
}, {})

console.log(listCounted)
```